# What is the GPIO voltage level of a ATMega32U4 when powered from USB?

Tags: usb, avr, gpio

I found a nice little device that utilizes the [ATMega32U4](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7766-8-bit-AVR-ATmega16U4-32U4_Datasheet.pdf).

[image]

Although I tried to find this particular information in the datasheet, I couldn't (more than 400 pages):

When this tiny chip is powered directly from USB:

- What are the voltage levels on it's GPIO pins?
- Can I have 3.3V levels on GPIO when this chip sources power directly from USB?

Can you please help me finding this information?

Comment: This is how you search for information:  1) Type "atmega32u4 datasheet" in a search engine. 2) Click on the search result leading to Microchip's official site.
  https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/atmel-7766-8-bit-avr-atmega16u4-32u4_datasheet.pdf  3) In the pdf scroll down to "Electrical characteristics" 4) Note that the first thing there, DC characteristics, lists  VCC = 2.7V to 5.5V. Reading the features of this MCU at the very beginning of The Friendly Manual also reveals "Operating Voltages 2.7 - 5.5V". Further reading of "DC characteristics" answers the rest.

Comment: @Lundin :) You are correct. But one can misunderstand the itentions of your comments. Maybe Daniel is not used to reading datasheets and got lost somewhere

Answer (score 1):

When there is no LDO on the board (could be on the bottom-side, but I doubt it) the IC will be powered vom USB 5V0 +/- 10%. According to the datasheet, Page 383:

> Output-High Voltage ( Vcc=5V ) is min 4.2V

Therefore, I would conclude that this device (when powered from USB 5V0 and with no LDO on board) will work with 5V0 GPIOs.

**Edit:**

According to the datasheet ( Page 4 ), there is an internal LDO. But it is used to provide the USB signal reference potential. It can not be used to power external devices.

The blockdiagramm also shows, that there is no internal LDO within the VCC path.

Therefore: Your device will have 5V GPIOs.

Comment: I wish to use SPI to drive an OLED screen, with 3.3V tolerant SPI.

Comment: @Daniel If your product ist just for fun and only requires slowisch bitrates you can connect 1k Series-resistors to every SPI (SCK,MOSI,MISO,CS and additional GPIOs) signal. Your OLED will most likely have internal Over-Voltage protection (Current limited by the resistors - so no harm to your part ... most likely) and the MCU will accept 3V3 signals as "HIGH". BUT: This is a "dirty" solution for hobby use. Also: The series resistors will limit your maximal bitrates due to the RC-Filter effect they have

Answer (score 1):

The GPIO pins are at VCC level. On your board, if VCC is directly connected to 5V, GPIO will be at 5V if there is an LDO like shown below, GPIO will be at the LDO voltage level.

From datasheet that you provided, here is the relevant diagram to look at
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The IO supply can be anything, as it is set by the PCB connections.

It can't be found on MCU datasheet, it can only be found from the product data sheet or other documentation.

The MCU itself allows the IO pin supply to be 3.3V, but for that prodcut, it can't be guessed.

It may or may not have an LDO. Dozens of online shops sell it and describe what voltage board it is. Don't consider buying from places that don't bother to specify the voltage.

However, most places define it uses 5V.